# HTML CSS, ::after additions do not respect the overflow:hidden of the parent

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

The following code does not respect the overflow:hidden boundaries, and this is causing a mess with my code where I have many consecutive lines.

You can see (jsfiddle below) that it does respect it with regard to the text ("Test"), but not with what is defined in the ::after item.

How can I solve / workaround this?

UPDATE: it makes sense that by removing the position:absolute in the ::after element then the boundaries are respected, but then the "icon" is not seen anymore

**html**

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div><a href="/" class="btn icon">Test</a></div>
  <div><a href="/" class="btn icon">Test</a></div>
  <div><a href="/" class="btn icon">Test</a></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
body { padding: 50px 0; }

.wrap {
    background: grey;
    height:18px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.btn {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.icon {}

.icon::after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:6px;
    margin-top:1px;
    width:4px;
    height:6px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #444;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jsedv6kw/1/

Comment: That's a suspiciously empty `.icon {}` rule...

Comment: That's a habit I am taking, to leave written for some important-for-me elements the css rules even if they're empty, as a reminder. Here it looks suspicious because it looks like a prepared Q&A I guess :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
.icon {position: relative;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jsedv6kw/2/

Answer (score 3):

```
.wrap {
  background: grey;
  height:18px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

You are missing 
      **position:relative;**
http://jsfiddle.net/jsedv6kw/3/

Answer (score 2):

Give `position:relative;` to `.wrap`, as position property creates layers of elements.

Comment: In the immediate parent already works, as suggested above, but thank anyway!

Answer (score 1):

after... must be dispaly:block

```
.icon::after {
    **dispaly:block**
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:6px;
    margin-top:1px;
    width:4px;
    height:6px;
    background:#fff;
    border:1px solid #444;
    opacity:0.8;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work as you say when tested on the fiddle (?)